# What is the error called when two letters are mistakenly swapped?

Tags: single-word-requests, errors, typography, metathesis

Generally this may be called *typo* but when particularly two letters of a word are mistakenly swapped, what is this error called? Some examples:

> teh > the
>   fromat > format
>   comptuer > computer

Comment: A symptom of dyslexia?

Comment: One's typing will need to be pretty bad... before it seems like a symptom of dyslexia.

Comment: Someone give this bloke's question an upvote!!!!

Comment: @Ham: IMHO this is a kind of common typing error for people which type fast with 10 fingers like programmers.

Comment: I particularly experience this kind of a problem when i am planning to type one letter with the left hand fingers and other with the right hand fingers alternatively.. And most of the times my right hand moves so fast that even before my left finger types a letter my right hand types two.

Comment: When it has a comical result, it's a [Spoonerism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism).

Comment: I usually call it a tpyo. Of course, when typing that I accidentally entered "typo" and had to go back and uncorrect it...

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: Usually it's because of fingers landing on the keys in wrong seqence.

Comment: @sharptooth, I woludn't konw !

Answer (score 107, accepted):

That is called a [*transposition error*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_error#Transposition_Error), and is very common for reasonably speedy touch-typists. The text editor Emacs even has a basic control chord (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to swap (transpose) the preceding two characters.

From Wikipedia's [transcription error page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_error#Transposition_Error):

> Transposition errors are commonly
>   mistaken for transcription errors, but
>   they should not be confused. As the
>   name suggest, transposition errors
>   occur when characters have
>   “transposed” — that is, they have
>   switched places. Transposition errors
>   are almost always human in origin. The
>   most common way for characters to be
>   transposed is when a user is touch
>   typing at a speed that makes them
>   input one character, before the other.
>   This may be caused by their brain
>   being one step ahead of their body.
>
> Examples of Transposition Error
>
> Input : Gergory Instead of : Gregory
>
> Input : 23rd of Auguts Instead of :
>   23rd of August
>
> Input : Johsua Instead of : Joshua

Comment: +1 seems the most precise answer to what OP is looking for, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_error#Transposition_Error

Comment: @Unreason - Oooh. That link is way better than the one I used. I'm "borrowing" it.

Comment: The one I always see: Micheal for Michael.

Comment: @GEdgar, how often is that in fact a misspelling rather than a typo?  More often than not I'd bet; also Micheal is a not-unusual name in its own right.

Comment: *I cnduo't bvleiee taht I culod aulaclty uesdtannrd waht I was rdnaieg. Unisg the icndeblire pweor of the hmuan mnid, aocdcrnig to rseecrah at Cmabrigde Uinervtisy, it dseno't mttaer in waht oderr the lterets in a wrod are, the olny irpoamtnt tihng is taht the frsit and lsat ltteer be in the rhgit pclae. The rset can be a taotl mses and you can sitll raed it whoutit a pboerlm. Tihs is bucseae the huamn mnid deos not raed ervey ltteer by istlef, but the wrod as a wlohe. Aaznmig, huh? Yaeh and I awlyas tghhuot slelinpg was ipmorantt! See if yuor fdreins can raed tihs too.*

Comment: @Unreason Spelling is still important. It makes reading a lot easier :)

Comment: @Unreason: Astonishing! I really couldn't detect that I was reading that any slower than if everything had been transcibed as normal!

Comment: `xp` is the 'transpose' command in the text editor *vi*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, see http://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/Cmabrigde/ (more interesting things towards the end of the article) :)

Comment: @Agos: I really didn't transcibe it like that on purpose, and it took a while for me to spot the mistake even after you made it obvious there must be one! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers funny thing: I didn't notice your typo, I just found your name very relevant to the discussion :)

Comment: @Agos: This is getting surreal! Stop now before the system sends us off into 'chat'!

Comment: Dang! - looks like this Q is going viral! If I hadn't wasted a couple of minutes nitpicking with @Colin Fine over *Metathesis* I could have collected my biggest ever haul of rep points for a single answer! It's up to 49 now, so I'll check back later to see if the colour changes when it hits 50...

Comment: @Anguish Languish: actually it isn't. 'xp' isn't a command, it's a sequence of two commands 'x' to remove a character and 'p' to paste whatever is in the past buffer. Whether it was a cunning plan or a happy accident that the sequence suggested an abbreviation for 'transpose', I don't know.

Comment: @Unreason http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/is-it-true-that-only-the-positions-of-the-first-and-last-letter-in-a-word-matter

Answer (score 19):

Metathesis.

This word is most often used of swapping sounds, but the OED defines it as "The transposition of sounds or letters in a word, or (occas.) of whole words or syllables; the result of such a transposition".

Comment: Technically speaking that's the word, but I think it's very much a linguistics term. In normal parlance I just say "transposition" anyway.

Comment: +1 http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/M/metathesis.htm

Comment: ...added to which *metathesis* is generally understood to produce a recognised/recognisable *result*. So I would say **pwn**, for example, could be thus described. But I'm not so keen on calling OP's **comptuer** an example of metathesis.

Comment: @FimbleFingers: good point about the restricted field. But don't understand the relevance of "pwn". Most linguistic use of "metathesis" is about language change, so the "recognised result" is rather moot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't think the result *must* be an existing word, quote: 'Metathesis is responsible for the most common types of speech errors, such as children acquiring *spaghetti* as *pasketti*.' (wikipedia). I think you are misled by the fact that it usually does (as it is most effective as literary or rhetorical device when it does end up with recognizable result; however it does not prove nor imply that it must be so).

Comment: @Unreason: Perhaps I overstated the case. In the end, all I wanted to say was that *transposition* fits OP's request better. I see @T.E.D. has now put that up and it's raced ahead on upvotes, so I think others feel as I do.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen "type twister". In German, there's a term for numbers getting twisted, "Zahlendreher" ...

Comment: Is there a literal translation of "Zahlendreher"?

Comment: @Andrew “number twister”. Although it *should* really be “digit twister”, i.e. “Zifferndreher” (but I’ve never seen the latter).