# Say I wrote down 25 instead of 52 by accident. What is the right verb I can use here to specify what I did to these two digits?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, numbers

I'm looking for a verb/some verbs here so I can say:

I (verb) those two digits and that's why you read 25 here (instead of 52).

I don't want to use "mix up" because I'd like to specify this "action" between two digits 2 and 5. I hope I made myself clear. Thank you!

Comment: You ***switched*** them around. This is quite a basic question, which suggests that you might find our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) a better place to ask future questions. ELU here mainly deals with more advanced topics of the oddities and usage of the English language.

Comment: Swapped or switched around. Nobody ever says "transposed". I am cautious to migrate this to ELL, as you can simply take the verb in your mother tongue and then look up the translation in a bilingual dictionary of your choice.

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32889/what-is-the-error-called-when-two-letters-are-mistakenly-swapped/32897#32897

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Sorry if this is off-topic for this site. I wasn't aware of your sister site and I just got this verb on the tip of my tongue so I thought I'd just drop a question here. My bad.

Comment: I **always** say "transposed". People with dyslexia sometimes see letters transposed from their actual position, which can cause confusion and amusement with large signs such as "FCUK" (French Connection UK, a clothing store).

Answer (score 7):

I *transposed* those two digits.

More colloquially, you can say "I switched those two digits round".

Comment: I would not use _transpose_ here unless the meaning were completely clear—with something like numbers, I would probably be more likely to think that you transposed the _intact set of numbers_ to somewhere else. Perhaps that is just the coder in me being biased, though.

Comment: *transposed* is perfect for this.

Answer (score 1):

Transpose - cause two or more things to change place