# Why is there confusion between depreciated and deprecated?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, confusables

For at least a year and half, I read "deprecated" as "depreciated", even when writing it down myself, I would spell it as "depreciated", even though pretty much every time I read it, it was spelt correctly (the intended meaning, was the meaning of "deprecated").

(When I finally spoke the word in conversation, obviously in the wrong context, and got told I should use deprecated, I was somewhat freaked out, especially after reading the same material I previously had, only to find it had all magically changed.)

I see from Stack Overflow I'm not the only one: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=depreciated

Can depreciated have a similar meaning to deprecated in any circumstances? (And why after reading it spelt correctly so many times, or just after the first, would I say it in my head and write it down incorrectly?)

Secondly, what is the difference between deprecated and obsolete?

Comment: Don't do that to me, man! I now feel compelled to go on a StackOverflow editing spree with that link...

Comment: I recently had to correct a seasoned and otherwise competent developer when he told me "the function is depreciated". It's crazy how wide spread this is.

Comment: Code monkeys can't speel.

Comment: And don't get me started on their misuse of the semicolon.

Comment: For me, recently, pain ceased to be soaring and started searing...

Comment: They're confused because they're spelled similarly enough to confuse people. If they heard them instead of looking at them, there'd be no problem.

Answer (score 45):

The main difference is that *deprecate* is largely archaic, apart from its very modern computing sense. The original meaning (derived from Latin *de=away*, and *prevari=pray*) meant to ward something off (by prayer, for example). It can also be used to mean *to express disapproval of; deplore; belittle*, but IMHO this is also dated/poetic usage outside computing. I also suspect it's used as something of a euphemism for *denigrate*, which to some people is uncomfortably close to the n-word.

---

*Deprecated* is normally used today for some feature of a computer language which is still supported, but no longer recommended. It may *not* be supported at some time in the future, because it doesn't fit well with the way the language is being developed.

There's no substantive difference in meaning between *deprecated* and *obsolete* for that "no longer recommended" computer sense. But *obsolete* is used in far more contexts than *deprecated*, and can sometimes imply "no longer *capable* of being used", rather than just "not recommended".

---

*Depreciated*, on the other hand, derives from Latin *pretium=price*. It's used of things which have reduced in value over time.

---

TL;DR: People either confuse the words because they don't know what they mean, or because they don't notice the extra letter "i" in one of them.

Comment: I would argue that there is a qualitative difference between "deprecated" and "obsolete". Something can continue to be useful, but it's not encouraged. It might never be supplanted by something else to make it obsolete.

Comment: @Andrew Vit: Both "deprecated" and "obsolete" imply there's a newer alternative which is either better right now, or will be better soon. But in both cases there's also the implication that the older method/product does still work, *and* the implication that the user should "upgrade". If there's a difference, I don't think that's it.

Comment: I don't think *deprecate* is archaic. I see "self-deprecation" and "self-deprecatory humour" frequently enough. (It's not actually *self-depreciation*, is it?)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I certainly wouldn't call the *self-* forms archaic, but I do think they're a little poetic/flamboyant/dated. Not much, though.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer, but one extra point which I think is in play: both these words are fairly unusual, so when people are wavering between the two, I suspect *depreciated* gets a big boost from the analogy with *appreciated*, which is much more common than either.

Comment: @PLL: I can appreciate what you're saying there. Not that I personally would *depreciate* your point if I didn't understand/agree with you, but it's easy to see how less fluent speakers might do that.

Comment: Actually… doing some Ngramming, the results are very interesting, comparing different forms of `appreciate,depreciate,deprecate`. For most forms (*-ate*, *-ates*, *-ated*), *appreciate* wins out by about 4–10x, while *depreciate* beats *deprecate*, but not by nearly as much as I would have expected.  For *-ation*, *depreciation* comes up much higher — about half as common as *appreciation* — while *deprecation* is almost unknown.  Conversely, with *-ating*, *deprecating* beats out *depreciating*, and more strongly in recent years — largely in *self-deprecating* as @ShreevatsaR suggests.

Comment: @PLL: The one I'd have bet the farm on is *deprecated/depreciated*, where I've no doubt the former has shot up in the last decade or so. It's not that clear in NGrams, partly because they haven't got much post-2000 stuff indexed yet. But on standard Google, *deprecated* today gets over *ten times more hits*, whereas the present tense *deprecate* doesn't even get three times more than *depreciate*. That's because in the modern computer sense, *deprecated* is used more like an adjective than a past participle.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have to disagree with your implication of "newer alternative". Obsolete means it's old. Maybe there is a newer alternative or it's not needed at all any longer. OTOH, deprecated is just "unpreferred". A direct memory drawing may be deprecated because using the high-level API is vastly easier and safer, but if you absolutely must have the extreme write speeds of direct write, you'll choose it instead nevertheless, and it's not going to go anywhere - it's still the only and correct way to get correct results in specific situations.

Comment: @SF.: The original meaning (now, effectively *obsolete* :) of *deprecate* was a lot stronger than simply "unpreferred" (it meant you *earnestly prayed* for it not to exist). So I think the word today only has meaning in the computer context, where it always means *There's a better method available now. This old method is currently still supported, but be warned that it might not be in future*. And so far as *obsolete* is concerned, I think there's always the implication that an obsolete thing has been replaced by something newer and better.

Comment: Although correct and objective aside from the stated opinion about the value of the word _deprecate_, I think this answer ignores the context of the original poster.  The "very modern computer sense" is the entire context of the question. In software development, _deprecated_ is widely used. The word has a commonly understood meaning and is even clearly defined as an official term in many standards and API documents. The word _depreciated_ is not used in this context, but is often used when discussing subjects with a financial value.

Comment: @Vince: Having used MS development software for many decades, I'm intimately familiar with ***deprecated*** as used in ***its very modern computing sense*** - as referred to in the very first sentence of my answer. But obviously there wouldn't be any scope for the "confusion" OP asks about *if it were not for that modern (revived) sense*, because the word "deprecated" would hardly ever get used anyway!

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary gives "belittle" as a synonym for both words.  As FumbleFingers points out, "deprecate" means to "pray away" and "depreciate" means to "price away", so they aren't *that* far apart.

Answer (score 2):

People get confused because the spellings of the two words are nearly identical. When we read, we don't read every individual character, we just process a few letters and make a guess.

That may sound like I'm pointing out the obvious, but it gets a bit more interesting. The spelling difference between "deprecated" and "depreciated" is towards the center of the two words, which turns out to be the real problem.
 [A study was done at Cambridge University](http://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/Cmabrigde/) which showed `it deosn't mttaer in waht oredr the ltteers in a wrod are, the olny iprmoetnt tihng is taht the frist and lsat ltteer be at the rghit pclae.`

Edit: It appears that the study was never actually conducted, and the claim is not true as stated, but there is still some truth to it.

Intuitively it still seems to me that altering letters in towards the middle of a word would have less of an effect than altering the extremities, especially the first letter. Unfortunately I don't know of any reputable study to support my claim, so I'll leave it at that.

Edit2: Snopes lists this as [undetermined](http://www.snopes.com/language/apocryph/cambridge.asp).

Comment: That study is now depreciated - it mostly only works for words that are short.

Comment: @MartinBeckett It's not depreciated, if anything it's apprecated.

Comment: BTW, if you click the link you'll find that actually no such study was done at Cambridge University. And it's not true that only the first and last letter matter; try the "The sprehas had ponits and patles" sentence that's near the bottom of the page. [This has been discussed before on English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/is-it-true-that-only-the-positions-of-the-first-and-last-letter-in-a-word-matter).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Damn...so disillusioning.

Comment: But do read your link for lots interesting stuff on the importance of letter position and word recognition, including a literature review and a PhD on this.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Dang! It took me the best part of a minute to figure out even the *sherpas/pitons/plates* reading, and until I followed your link it never occured to me there could be several alternatives. That isn't the only ELU post about this though, because I know I commented on one a few months back, and it's not the one you linked to. But I'll never find it with the current site search facilities, I know.