# Antonym of "recommend"

Tags: verbs, antonyms

What's the antonym of *recommend*? For example:

> I **recommend** that item!

I tried to use *unrecommend*, but the spell-checker throws an error and it sounds stupid as well!

Comment: what happened to the good old "not recommend"?

Comment: Is that an antonym? :P

Comment: why not? I mean if "advice against" is acceptable, so should "not recommend".

Comment: I vote for a new word: decommend. :-)

Comment: Is there a scale to this? If so, can I say there's no opposite?

Comment: Not recommend is not really the opposite of recommend, merely the absence of it.  I hate roller coasters,  I would not recommend them to anyone.  However that does not mean I would advise against them, to each there own.

Comment: How about "Contraindicated" ?

Comment: Technically speaking I think the antonym of recommend is "no opinion on that". In common usage a recommendation can be positive or negative "The committee recommends not purchasing a  chocolate teapot."

Comment: @BenRobinson "That course of action is not recommended" - how neutral does that sound?

Comment: @sq33G Everything needs to be viewed in context: "That course of action is recommended", "That course of action is not recommended", "I advise against that course of action".  Positive, neutral, negative.

Comment: @James Anderson: Your committee sounds pretty "on the ball". Could you perhaps get them to give some advice to the European Central Bank?

Comment: most [antonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/recommend) mentioned in answers

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/recommend

Comment: "not recommend" is neutral.  "recommend against" is anti-

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I would suggest “advise against.”

Comment: +1 I would suggest against not using "advise against" :)

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng Well, *I* would *advise against* not using '*advise against*'.

Comment: I would again devise your suggestion.

Comment: Missed opportunity: I would _recommend_ "advise against."

Answer (score 54):

M-W dictionary lists no antonyms.

Dictionary.com lists:  disapprove, discourage, dissuade but I don't think those really fit as direct antonyms.

Usually in my experience you'd say *recommend against*.

---Update to add--- As FumbleFingers mentioned in a comment, *advise against* is an equally valid alternative (and seemingly more popular in British English, as [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20advise%20against,I%20recommend%20against&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) would suggest).

Comment: I think "dissuade" is a pretty good choice.

Comment: Depending on the exact context, I think that discourage and dissuade could fit the bill.

Comment: @Lars and Bjorn:   Depending on context, yes, but in a sentence:  "I recommend the blue sweater" you could not directly substitute:  "I discourage the blue sweater" or "I dissuade the blue sweater".  That is why I believe it is not a true antonym, though it can be used to convey a similar idea.

Comment: @Lynn To me, "I discourage the blue sweater" sounds perfectly cromulent.

Comment: @fluffy: I would say, "I discourage you from wearing the blue sweater." which is subtly different.  But to each his own! :)

Comment: @fluffy: "I discourage the blue sweater" makes me think you hurt the sweater's feelings (or confidence). Does "I discourage the dog" mean recommending against buying the dog? A sentence like "I discourage Mary for the role of president" would be very weird to me if you used it to mean that you were dissuading *others* from electing Mary, rather than discouraging Mary herself.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Hm, good point.

Comment: -1: It simply isn't true that people usually say *recommend against*. As [this NGram shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+advises+against%2Che+recommends+against&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), *"he **advises** against"* outnumbers *"he recommends against"* by about 5:1.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You are correct, but I was not trying to compare those two specific phrases but merely to give a common phrase.  But as [this NGram shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+advise+against%2CI+recommend+against&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3) - in American English "I advise against" and "I recommend against" are pretty darn close in overall usage (recently), and in my *personal* experience people usually say the latter.

Answer (score 42):

Strictly speaking, [*discommend*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discommend) is the antonym, although it doesn't work in all contexts, and has become nearly obsolete.

I agree with @breen that *advise against* is the modern antonym phrase.

Comment: Nice find! "Discommend" is an excellent word - it sounds as funny as "unpossible", but it's legitimate. And it's clearer to say "I discommend X" than "I don't recommend X", because the latter could mean I'm neutral on the matter. I say let's bring it back. :)

Comment: @NathanLong good point re: the neutrality of "I don't recommend"… I agree, we should rescue this word from obscurity! Letting this word fade into obscurity is discommendable!

Comment: By the way, I found the [Google Ngram of discommend](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discommend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and linked sample uses fascinating! It appears to have dropped out of use in the last half of the 1800s.

Comment: I really want to use this word for the sole purpose of being able to prove certain people wrong when they try to tell me it's not a word :)

Comment: @Brandon Moore: On that basis, you could also use *discountenance, disesteem,* and *disfavor*. But don't blame me if you get accused of being a pretentious prat.

Comment: @ghoppe: I hate to disagree with such a highly-rated answer, but I think "strictly speaking", *discommend* is the antonym of *commend* - which in practice is not a very close synonym of *recommend* in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The [OED shows](http://photo.pds.org:5004/view/Entry/53825?redirectedFrom=discommend#eid) that discommend has three meanings, the first with citations from 1509, is the opposite of commend; the second, cited as a usage since 1533, is the opposite of recommend; and the third, now obsolete, means *to cause (anything) to be unfavourably viewed or received.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also, do you really find *disfavour* to be pretentious or obscure? I think it's not uncommon, especially used in the phrase *fall into disfavour*.

Comment: @ghoppe: To *fall into disfavour* is still current, but I think using it as as a verb would be hopelessy archaic. IMHO the same applies to *any* use of "discommend" today, no matter what OED says about usage in centuries past.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ha, don't worry I'm only going to do it with people I already know to be pretentious ;)

Comment: @Brandon Moore: In which case you *won't* be pretentious. You'll simply be poking fun at them, perhaps with the added *frisson* of knowing that they might not realise you're doing it ha ha.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps you missed my caution with the words "nearly obsolete" in my answer? My citation of the OED was used to refute your assertion, not cite current usage.

Comment: @ghoppe: You're quite right - this comment thread has gotten so long I was just looking at your comment in isolation. Your answer is also quite right in that discommend wouldn't really pass muster in many/any contexts today, when the best choice is invariably *advise against*. Maybe it's just me though, but I feel that today most usages of *commend* that aren't self-conciously "mock-archaic" have more the sense of *praise, admire* than *recommend, endorse, vouch for*.

Answer (score 24):

In technical computer manuals we use the word "deprecate".

Comment: great minds, and all that...

Comment: Fun at restaurants too;  The `Pad Thai` here is deprecated.  Recommend the `Pad-See-Ew` instead

Comment: "deprecate" does also have the additional meaning of "this isn't guaranteed to work in the future, stop using it now and get used to the correct alternative".  So it's more a subset of the answer...  Still, +1 because I see it so often  (x_x)

Comment: @Izkata: I think it's fair to say that "additional meaning" is *specifically* the meaning applicable in the computer sense. But the broader meaning was always there long before the word was co-opted by geekspeak, and just because it's fallen into obscurity because of confusion with "depreciate" is no reason why it can't come back into more general use. After all, *discommend* is even rarer and more archaic, and that's currently the top-rated answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would argue that the new meaning of "deprecate" would make it simply confusing if used outside of the context of the new meaning, while "discommend" doesn't have that problem, because it's fallen out of use instead of having evolved with the language.

Comment: @NasBanov No, I am thinking of ["deprecate"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

Comment: @Izkata: I would argue that Warren P's example is perfectly valid (and amusing), and carries no suggestion that said Pad Thai is likely to close down. Unless it's from lack of custom because everyone in the local area takes notice of Warren's pronouncements on eateries.

Answer (score 16):

`discourage` fits somewhat, but not by itself.

"I discourage you from using that item."

Comment: This use of *discourage* sounds odd to me.

Comment: Agreed it's very odd in this "bare" form. But *"I would discourage you from..."* is quite common.

Answer (score 13):

As @breen and others have said, the standard phrasing for the opposite of *I recommend* is probably *I advise against*.

But if you're not really interested in specifying *who* advises against something, you might consider [deprecate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deprecate) - *to express earnest disapproval of*. Saying something is **deprecated** is standard terminology [in the context of software components/methods](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45295/why-is-there-confusion-between-depreciated-and-deprecated), but there's no reason why it couldn't be used more widely.

Usage for *deprecated* was declining before its recent revival in computing, probably because of [overlap with depreciate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45295/why-is-there-confusion-between-depreciated-and-deprecated). But for the time being I'd stick with the past particple, and avoid, for example, *"I deprecate that course of action"*.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest "caution against."

Answer (score 5):

"I recommended against that item"

Answer (score 4):

*Upvote*:

I recommend that answer. | That answer is recommended.

*Downvote*:

I **advise against** that answer. | That answer is **ill-advised**.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I'm surprised that no one has suggested **deplore**.  While I concur with many of the other answers, I would not encourage, advocate, urge, esteem, or prescribe their use.

Answer (score 2):

How about,

- I disapprove of this item
- I discourage using this item
- I dissuade using this item

Comment: I think "dissuade" is normally transitive. You should mention who you are dissuading. "I dissuade you from using this item." Even then, it sound presumptuous that you would be successful. "I would dissuade people from using this item." or "I'd try to dissuade you from using this item."

Answer (score 1):

Come on, **upvote** means **recommend** while **downvote** means the opposite!

So please **recommend** my answer to the OP simply means **upvote** my answer please!

Just for fun :)

Comment: Simplest yet most insightful answer ever!!! Good job, Terry :)

Comment: -1. Should be community wiki, or a comment, rather.

Answer (score 1):

Ye who arrived here as I did, hunting antonyms for this word on google, perhaps consider also:

- **condemn** - express complete disapproval of, *typically in public*
- **censure** - express severe disapproval of, *typically in a formal statement*.
- **denounce** - *publicly declare* to be wrong or evil.
- **decry** - publicly denounce [so... denounce, then?]
- **criticize** - *indicate the faults* of, in a disapproving way.
- **vilify** - speak or write about in an *abusively* disparaging manner.
- **deprecate** - express disapproval of. [Suggested by others]
- **proscribe** - 1) forbid, especially by law. 2) denounce or condemn.
- **disparage** - regard or represent as being *of little worth.*

(All definitions from Google's define command, with my italics to highlight main differences in usage, and my [comments])

Comment: "proscribe" is what I needed, thanks! It can be contrasted against "prescribe", like "The doctor prescribes arrowroot" (you _should_ eat arrowroot) vs. "The doctor proscribes arrowroot" (you should _not_ eat arrowroot)

Answer (score 0):

> disapprove, discourage, dissuade

Those are the words, now you must know in which situation each should be used.

Comment: It would help if you could examples of each being in use.

Comment: ok, for example the first one disapprove/discourage
"I recomend the use of drugs" it would be "I disapprove/discourage the use of drugs" don't have in mind a phrase for the last one English isn't my language, I speak portuguese

Answer (score 0):

How about simply "recommend against"

> I recommend against doing so

Answer (score -2):

I would simply negate `recommend` into `do not recommend`

eg: I recommend x. I do not reccomend y.

Comment: "do not recommend" describes the absence of recommendation.    This is not the same as advising against something, which is the opposite of recommending it.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Technically you are correct, but in everyday speak, saying “I do not recommend it” is an advisement against it. Never have I heard someone say “I don’t recommend something” when they mean they simply don’t have an opinion on it. Possibly, they might say “I don’t *necessarily* recommend it.”

Comment: Coming back to this now, I agree with you.  I'm not sure why I didn't see it that way a year ago!