# Antonym for "recommendation"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The context is a template for a wiki page, specifically in a line of instructions for page authors to complete:

> Summary of findings, recommendations or ***anti-recommendations*** for implementation or further study, ...

I suppose I could say:

> ... recommendations for or against implementation or further study ...

but as I was writing it, I wondered whether there might be a way to rewrite this to conjoin the nouns instead of the prepositions.

I see this question for the verb form: [Antonym of "recommend"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48660/49890)

Comment: It is hard to find a good antonym ... I'd use non-recommendation.

Comment: There is the common medical term http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraindication ("indication against [x]") which you could use directly (*"Summary of findings and their indications or contraindications for implementation"*) or from that, I make *contrarecommendations* with a whole 6 Google results.

Comment: If you place "*criticisms*" before recommendations, you escape the need to modify it with for implementation. Depending on the larger context: *Summary of findings, **criticisms**, [and?] recommendations for implementation or further study, ...*

Comment: How about *practice*? There are *[best practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_practice)* and *[worst practices](http://www.timethoughts.com/timemanagement/DefiningWorstPractices.htm)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is any antonym for recommendation that would be followed by *for*. So in any case you'd have to conjoin nouns *and* prepositions.

For example:

> - recommendations for and discouragement of...
> - recommendations for and criticism of
> - recommendations for and opposition to
> - recommendations for and disapproval of
> - recommendations for and condemnation of

I believe *recommendations for and against* works best.

Comment: I agree. You don't need an antonym of "recommend" to say that someone shouldn't do something, because you can recommend that someone not do something just like you can recommend that they do something.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to use [condemnation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condemnation):

> : a statement or expression of very strong and definite criticism or disapproval

It is probably not an exact antonym of recommendation (what is?) but, seated next to recommendation, it looks eloquent.