# Why is "depredate" the correct answer?

Tags: gre

I came across a question while practicing for my GRE.

> That Egyptologists believe the ancient Egyptians’ memory of the
>   Pharaoh Tutankhamun quickly faded after his death is based on the fact
>   that the Pharaoh’s tomb was not _______ in antiquity, but rather was
>   found nearly intact by twentieth-century archaeologists.
>
> **Options:** *defamed, denigrated, depredated, derided, developed*

I chose *depredated* by method of elimination. (it is the correct choice) but upon checking the reason -

> The clue phrase here is "found intact." Because of the pivot word "but
>   rather" before the clue, we know the first blank will disagree with
>   the clue. Thus we're looking for a filler like "robbed" or
>   "destroyed."

I can't get my head around why *depredate* is the filler. It doesn't make sense as whole in sentence. Can anyone elucidate on this ?

Comment: It's an *appalling* example sentence! But the only credible choice is the relatively rare word ***depredated*** *(plundered, ravaged, laid waste to)*. Any reasonably literate native speaker should be able to decipher the "tortured syntax" of the sentence, but I suspect many of them would need to consult a dictionary (as I just had to) to check that particular definition. Are they testing people's ability to handle cumbersome phrasing, or the breadth of their vocabulary?

Comment: Semantically deconstructed: The assertion *The ancient Egyptians’ memory of the Pharaoh Tutankhamun quickly faded after his death* is something Egyptologists believe. That belief is based on the fact that the Pharaoh’s tomb wasn't plundered in antiquity (presumably because the ancients forgot about that Pharaoh,  so it never occurred to anyone to find and loot the grave).

Comment: (As you'll see from this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=depredated%2Clooted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdepredated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clooted%3B%2Cc0), ***depredated*** virtually "flatlines" when compared to the more natural term ***looted***.)

Comment: _Looted_ is the word that would be correct in the blank. But I agree it's a terrible sentence.

Comment: if "rob" was included with 'depredate", it is trickily reasonable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers your collected comments would easily form a good answer ;-)

Comment: Although I "looted" may be clearer, I see nothing wrong with someone's tomb being depredated. The dictionary definitions I find give the meanings of "plunder", "pillage", "steal, without necessary connotations of violence or predation in the predator-prey sense. That's a very fitting word for someone who robs a tomb or a grave, because apart from the actual connotation of stealing, it also has a connotation of wrongfully disturbing a site, as would be the case if you robbed a tomb/grave. By the way I'm pretty sure his tomb was robbed twice in antiquity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Disagree that there’s anything poorly written here. It’s doing its job. The purpose of this question is ***NOT*** to try to find the most casual term possible that still conveys the intended meaning. The question was deliberately written this way to tease out whether you understand the difference between a bunch of polysyllabic Latinate verbs all beginning with *de-*.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm sure you're one of the relatively few people who would have actually *known* the verb ***depredate*** (I freely admitted I didn't, even though my *own* vocabulary is relatively extensive). I'd guess over 90% of people applying for degree courses *wouldn't* know the word. But like me, over 90% of *those* people would still pick the right answer, because they'd be able to eliminate all the other possibilities on the grounds of obvious semantic incompatibility. But certainly I'd expect well over 90% of such applicants to handle the convoluted syntax without any problems.

Comment: ...but I still don't know if it's intended to test (1) ability to parse cumbersome phrasing, (2) knowledge of a *very* obscure word, or (3) ability to reason logically (given prior familiarity with all the *wrong* options). Whatever - I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense to say ***looting*** is a "[most] casual" term in *any* context, even by way of contrasting it with ***depredating*** (which my Google spell-checker underlines in red - presumably because even *it* doesn't know the word! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh come now, my good sir: *depredation* is a perfectly common word. The OED places it in Frequency Band 4, no less.

Comment: @tchrist: What can I say? Google Books claims *millions* of hits for each of ***deprecated*** and ***depreciated*** - a distinction which 43 ***serious** English language enthusiasts* thought [worthy of an upvote here on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45295/), but only 15 thousand hits for ***depredated***. That's a pretty big difference, imho, and the fact that even Google Chrome's spell-checker doesn't recognise the word speaks volumes to me (if not to you, but I would never claim to be on your level as regards extensive vocabulary, as I'm sure you know! :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make sense of this question is to winnow out the answers that can't be correct.

The test question's sentence asserts a logical opposition between finding the tomb intact in the twentieth century and having the tomb **X** in antiquity, where **X** stands for one of five words: *defamed*, *denigrated*, *depredated*, *derided*, or *developed*. So the task is to figure out which of the five words works in direct opposition to "found intact."

The words *defamed*, *denigrated*, and *derided* share a similar sense of insult, mockery, or unfair criticism—but there is no obvious connection between a lack of defamation, denigration, or derision toward Tutankhamun and the historical fact that his tomb remained intact over the millennia. Likewise, the fact that the tomb was found intact has little connection to whether it was "developed" in antiquity—unless we imagine that parceling it out into condominiums would have resulted in considerably more wear and tear to the structure than it actually endured.

That leaves for our consideration the choice *depredated*—which means ransacked or plundered. Clearly, "remained intact" stands in strong opposition to "was depredated"; so the only remaining test is whether the whole sentence, with *depredated* in place, is tolerably logical. In my view, it is: the writer argues that the fact that the tomb escaped the depredations of grave robbers (and so remained intact through many centuries) is evidence that people living in the area quickly forgot about Tutankhamun and his tomb, and so were not inclined to seek it out and pillage it.

Maybe so, maybe not. But unquestionably an argument that links a tomb's intactness to an absence of depredation makes far more sense than an argument that links the tomb's intactness to an absence of defamation, denigration, derision, or development.

Answer (score 0):

"I can't get my head around why **rob/depredate** is the filler"

In the title to your question you referenced only **[depredate](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/depredate)**, but in the body of your question you reference **rob/depredate**.

**To depredate** does require more than basic use of and understanding of English, but **to rob** does not. As a test GRE test question, it appears apropos. It was not **'robbed' in antiquity**.